# Storing/Retrieving encrypted text in file using HTML5 File API

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to store and retrieve encrypted text in HTML5 file in Chrome using library as [As in this.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html)

Storing like below

```
var data = {a : 1};
data = encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), 'password', 256);

// Store it to a text file here..
```

Again get the stored like below

```
var data = evt.target.result // This is text of file store earlier.
data = JSON.parse(decrypt(data, 'password', 256)); // Should be {a : 1}
```

but getting error like below

`Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Encryption and Decryption is working fine with regular text content, but JSON it is failed. This is not particular to a single encryption library, observed in CryptoJS too.

Are there any precautions to be taken before storing encrypted text in text file. Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try quoting the JSON data like

```
data = "{a:1}"
```

Comment: so i used the json you posted in the URL you gave and it works there. Can you try with '{a : 1}' ?